# Bulk redirect all post

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I change my url
old = /category/post-title/
new = /tips/category/post-title/

I add tips after site url for all my posts. how I bulk redirect without list one by one?

Comment: You could do this a number of ways depending on how your site is setup. Are you using a plugin to manage redirects? Is your webhost Apache or nginx?

Comment: @admcfajn The issue is I use plugin I need to setup one by one. Iwant to avoid that way.

Comment: Just install [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) or [Safe Redirect Manager](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/safe-redirect-manager/)and use a wildcard redirect to send traffic from /category/(.*) to /tips/category/(.*)

Comment: @admcfajn my issue category is terms-slug which is dynamic.

Comment: That's what the (.*) represents, it grabs a url segment as a variable and passes it to the destination of the redirect.

Comment: Do you mean the /tips/ portion of the destination url is dynamic?

Comment: @admcfajn Now it success redirect I use plugin redirection in using regex ^/(?!tips)(.*) te get post does not contain /tips/ and redirect to /tips/$1, now other problem it also effect in page, while i need only to post